# How to search documents by version?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to search documents in Elastic Search index by version? I try this:

```
curl -XGET eshost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search -d '{query:{match:{_version:"2"}}}'
```

But it does not work.

I need such a query to get all documents, that have never been updated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot query or filter by _version - the problem is that that field is not indexed, so queries and filters cannot access it:

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Can-i-filter-query-by-version-td4044331.html

Answer (score 20):

Try using version

Returns a version for each search hit.

```
{
    "version": true,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only returns the version field of the latest version of a document. It does not say return 3 versions of the same document.

Answer (score 5):

you can search like normal and set version as true and it will return you count of all the versions for each document:

```
GET indextest/original/_search?pretty=true
{
    "version": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
GET index/item/_search?pretty=version
{
    "version": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter by version is not possible, you can just get the version of each document by set the parameter *"version" = true*